# Petting Zoo C++ / Inheritance Class/Subclasses

Tags: c++, inheritance, subclass

I got an exercise which should work with different classes and their relationship between different classes.

Functions that are working for different classes should be defined for an abstract basic class and then be used on objects, which class is a subclass from the basic one.

In this exercise I am supposed to show the advantages of separating into interface and implementation.

I'm supposed to imagine a zoo that contains many different animals. These animals should be divided into mammals, birds or fishes.

- visitors should be able to feed some of the animals (goats, goose, goldfish)
- while others cant be fed (bears, sharks)
- visitors should also be able to pet some of the animals like goats, while others like bears, birds and fish can't be pet
- some of the animals should have characteristic noises - fishes are silent
- also the pets should have a nickname (everyone of them)

I should implement class/subclass so that I am able to use

```
void feed ( Animal& Animal )
void pet ( mammal& mammal )
void noise ( mammal& mammal )
void noise ( bird& bird )
```

I should have 10 different animals - with at least 2 from every type (mammal, bird, fish) by using one of the functions (void feed etc) the animal should be asked if the desired operation is possible and then give back the answer as something like:

"The goat billy can be fed"

"the bear bruno doesn't like to be pet"

"the goose herta quarks"

The characteristics of the animals apply to their whole specie  (mammal, bird, fish are just specific animals)
and they are therefore independent from the instance (all goats can be fed - not just billy) 
the keyword "static" can be used to asign a class variable
"static const bool feedable = ;"
then the variable wont be applied again for each single instance, moreover it becomes certain
that the characteristic applies to every animal of the type.

use abstract basic class and only virtual methods. every animal/type should use its specific variable and method 
that it needs to work (there should be no bool petable for fish)

at the end we should also draw a diagram which shows the  inheritance in a tree structure

Sorry my English is pretty bad but I have no one else to ask - so I tried to explain it as good as I could

This is what I got so far:

**zoo.h**

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstring>

    using namespace std;

    // CAnimal abstract class

    class CAnimal {

        public:
            CAnimal() { strcpy(m_name, ""); }
            virtual ~CTier()  { }
            void setName(char *name)  { strcpy(m_name, name);       }
            virtual void introduce() { cout << "Hello, my name is " <<m_name <<end1; }
            virtual CAnimal* create(char *) = 0; // pure virtual method

        private:
            char m_name[50];
            };

    // CMammal

    class CSMammal : public CAnimal {
        public:
            CMammal() { }
            virtual ~CMammal() { }
            virtual void introduce() {
                CAnimal::introduce();
                cout <<"I am a mammal"<<end1;

            }
    };

    // CFish

    class CFish : public CAnimal {
        public:
            CFish() { }
            virtual ~CFish() { }
            virtual void introduce() {
                CTier::introduce();
                cout << "I am a Fish" <<end1;

            }
    };

    // CBird

    class CBird : public CAnimal {
        public:
            CBird(){ }
            virtual ~CBird() { }
            virtual void introduce() {
                CTier::introduce();
                cout << "I am a Bird" <<end1;

            }
    };

    // Tierart  - legt eine Klasse an, welche von Vogel, Fisch oder Säugetier abgeleitet ist. Der Konstruktor legt die individuellen Namen fest.

    #define ANIMALTYPE(cname,parentclass,whoami)
        class name : public parentclass
        {
            public:
                cname(char *name) { CTier::setName(name); }
                /* Default-Konstruktor für Kreirrepresäntant */
                cname() { }
                void introduce() {
                    parentclass::introduce();
                    cout << "Ich bin " << whoami <<end1;

                }
            /* Kreirfunktion: Forward Ownership! */
            CTier* create(char *name) { return new cname(name); }

        };
```

and this is my **zoo.cpp**

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include "zoo.h"


    // giving names
    char *namen[] = { "Mehmet", "Aykut", "Dumbo", "Helga", "Henni",
    "KQLY", "Pasha", "Huan", "Emilio", "Blume" };
    const int namZahl = sizeof(namen) / sizeof(*namen);

    // Tierarten (Klassen anlegen)
    SPEZIES(CGoat, CMammal, "a Goat")
    SPEZIES(CPenguin, CBird, "a Penguin")
    SPEZIES(CGoldfish, CFish, "a Goldfish")
    SPEZIES(CBaer, CMammal, "a Baer")
    SPEZIES(CGoose, CBird, "a Goose")
    SPEZIES(CShark, CFish, "a Shark")
    SPEZIES(CBadge, CMammal, "a Badger")
    SPEZIES(CSalmon, CFisch, "a Salmon")
    SPEZIES(CBlackbird, CBird, "a Blackbird")
    SPEZIES(CElefant, CMammal, "an Elefant")

// main methode

int main(void) {
```

So now I don't know how to implement those other "voids" which will give me the information if I can feed the animal + using the static command for the rest of the exercise.

Comment: You should really think about using `std::string`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better design in this case would be to move all common behavior to the base class which would be abstract and then let subclasses implement specific behavior in their own way. For e.g :-

```
MakeNoise();
```

is supported by every animal, so you can easily include that in base class as pure virtual function. However, if you consider *feeding of animals* be included in base class in same way as `MakeNoise` then you wouldn't get intuitive behavior. For e.g :-

```
Feed(Item x);
```

Sharks are not to be feeded. How would you translate it in design. Make that functions throw error in Shark?

It would mean that Shark can be feeded but trying to feed them is error.

So, it's better if you just move this out of base class and implement it in terms of behavioral classes.

```
class Feedable {};
class Feed1 : public Feedable {};
```

and then implement these in classes where you want this behavior.